# Using for loop to change object references - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

```
    function calcul() {
        salaire = window.parseInt(document.myForm.txtSalaire.value);
        temps = window.parseInt(document.myForm.txtTemps.value);
        for (i = 0; i < monnaie.length; i++) {
            profit = monnaie[i] - (salaire/DIVISEUR) * temps;
            profit = profit.toFixed(3);
            document.myForm.txtMonnaie[i].value = monnaie[i] + "$";
            document.myForm.txtProfit[i].value = profit;
        }
    }
... <input type="text" name="txtMonnaie0"/>
```

I want to run through all my inputs to set new values to 'name="txtMonnaie[]"' and txtProfit[] using i as the parameter.

myForm.txtMonnaie is undefined.

Comment: How do you define `monnaie`?

Comment: You can't access DOM properties before you define them in your markup (i.e., put that script to the bottom of your `body` element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
 document.myForm.txtMonnaie[i].value = monnaie[i] + "$";
 document.myForm.txtProfit[i].value = profit;
```

To

```
 document.myForm["txtMonnaie" + i].value = monnaie[i] + "$";
 document.myForm["txtProfit" +i].value = profit;
```

If you have multiple elements with names like `txtProfit0`, `txtProfit1`, `txtProfit2`, ...
browser will not create an array with name txtProfit in `document.myForm`. There you will find just a list of properties like `document.myForm.txtProfit0`, `document.myForm.txtProfit1` ... and you can access them using index, just like it is shown above